# Is it possible to see a step by step execution of the code you are writing?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I am currently developing software for the web using visual studios and in the future I will be writing other thing using C# (among other languages). My question, is there a way to see the step by step execution of the code you wrote, outlining all the changes and procedures.

as an example, can i somehow see something that reads: "the function was executed with parameter value of 5. the value of y changed from 4 to 8. the string 'wording' now contains 20 characters. the function ABC executed for a second time with parameter 47." well you get the gist of it. I want to "read" my code after it executes. I feel like this would be the best debugger. Which brings me to my underlying goal of better debugging. So if you have any other 'techniques' for debugging, they would come a long way for a newbie.

Comment: Are you aware that you can step through the code as it executes, examining variable values as you go?

Answer (score 0):

[Runtime Flow](http://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) can show all executed functions with parameters, though configuring it for web projects is complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can look and learn how to use a debugger for instance the gdb debugger that allows you to step thru the instructions one at a time, and there is even reverse debugging now where you can step backwards thru the program ad execute the program backwards. Look at what gdb can do, and it will tell you what is possible.